# Oracle query keeps executing in batch

Tags: oracle, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have created a simple Oracle query in Windows server and i called it using BATCH script and scheduled it in TASK SCHEDULER in daily basis. It was executing properly before, but for the last three days it keeps on loading. In log, it shows "Loading Process Started... " but it never ends. Please help me to resolve this issue. 
This is my Query :

```
 SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT (*) > 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END)
  FROM DATA_table
 WHERE     TO_CHAR (CREATE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') =
              TO_CHAR (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND TABLE_STATUS NOT LIKE 'COMPLETED';
```

Comment: If you don't understand how StackOverFlow works with code formatting then don't bother to ask questions if you are going to keep getting rid of the edits people are making to your code formatting.  We will just vote to close your question.

Comment: 1. index table_status
2. change query expression to: table_status in ('<status a>', '<status b>', '<...>')

Comment: @RogerCornejo Is that a guess, or are you in possession of some additional information that we cannot see

Comment: You should not be doing character comparisons of DATE; they should remain dates. ie WHERE CREATE_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. If you are worried about the time portion the you should rephrase your query to be a between clause; WHERE CREATE_DATE BETWEEN ...

Comment: @RogrCornejo & BobC : thanks for your comments. Actually, the same query was working fine before. Suddenly it stops working (Keeps loading). I tried the same what you suggest, but still no luck. I installed Oracle client in the same server some three days back, will it be a issue?

Comment: Yeah, the issue happens because of the Oracle client installation. Windows task scheduler is using Program files's oracle sqlplus to connect oracle and execute the query. Once i installed the new oracle client in my D drive the script point the new sql plus which is available in my D drive, and it wont have a privilege to connec the Oracle. Thanks